# XPath conditional text node selection

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I need to construct an xpath string to select all descendants of a certain table with these conditions:

- The table is a descendant of a form with a specific `action` attribute value.
- The selected descendants are text nodes.
- The text node content can only contain whitespace.

It'll probably look something like:

```
//form[@action = "submit.html"]//table//text()[ ...? ]
```

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Here is my previous working compromise:

```
function KillTextNodes(rootpath)
{
    XPathIterate(rootpath + '//text()', function(node)
    {
        var tagname = node.parentNode.tagName;
        if (tagname != 'OPTION' && tagname != 'TH')
            Kill(node);
    });
}
```

Here is my function based on the accepted answer:

```
function KillTextNodes(rootpath)
{
    XPathIterate(rootpath + '//text()[not(normalize-space())]', function(node) { Kill(node); });
}
```

To explain my motivation a little - I'm iterating through the DOM with Javascript, and run into the same problem that many others do where unexpected empty text nodes throw off the results. This function helps me out a lot by simply deleting all of the empty text nodes so that my iteration logic can stay simple.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy (An  one-liner XPath expression) solution, :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hi there. I need to construct an xpath
>   string to select all descendants of a
>   certain table with these conditions:
>
> •The table is a descendant of a form
>   with a specific action attribute
>   value.
>
> •The selected descendants are
>   text nodes.
>
> •The text node content can
>   only contain whitespace.

**Use**:

```
//form[@action = "submit.html"]//table//text()[not(normalize-space())]
```

This selects all text nodes that have only white-space in them and that are descendents of any `table`that is a descendent of any `form` having an `action` attribute with value "submit.html".

Answer (score 1):

Text nodes containing whitespace only will be stripped from the document representation - i.e. there won't actually be a node. That means you can't access the text itself, but what you can do is match a parent lacking a text node using `not()` - something like:

```
//form[@action = "submit.html"]//table//*[not(text())]
```

Though in your case I would guess that will be far more aggressive than you actually intend. As an aside, be careful with these // matches, they're not very efficient and again very aggressive.

*(I've just noticed this isn't an XSLT question! If you're in JS land have you considered using DOM methods to get your list?)*

Comment: Yes, I've resorted to using the DOM, but applying XPath is much more preferable to pure DOM because pure DOM requires recursion (as far as I know). Regarding the stripping: Running Firefox 3.6.13, the example code I added to my question does indeed return whitespace-only text nodes, along with other text nodes.

Comment: You may run into x-browser issues then - I tested with IE7 and an XSLT editor - it would appear stripping is down to the engine in question.

Comment: I'm developing for Greasemonkey, so the list of targeted browsers is rather narrowed, but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: So. Under the assumption that I do indeed have the proper nodes in the document representation, can I somehow use this `normalize-space()` thing, or alternately a regular expression, to do the XPath selection?

Comment: @Reinderien: If white space only text nodes are preserved, then you could use `//form[@action = "submit.html"]//table//text()[not(normalize-space())]` or `//form[@action = "submit.html"]//table//text()[normalize-space()='']`

Comment: @annakata: Usually your answers are partially correct but this answer is quite obviously *not* correct at all. The question asks how to select *text* nodes and your answer selects elements that do not have any text nodes.